# Chart js annotation label issue

Tags: canvas, charts, chart.js

I'm using chart js, under annotation, label is getting hided at the right and left corner for chart box. Can anyone help how to apply z-index for annotation label ? Here is below reference image [image]

Comment: have your resolved your issue?please share the solution i am also facing the same problem

Comment: No I couldn't solve. Bcz I guess we cannot pull out the elements from x-axis and y-axis window.

Comment: then any work around you have did

Comment: yes.. I have created empty div outside plot, and on mouse-over of annotation-line or label I'm appending value inside empty div and hiding div on mouse-out